# Executable can't find SDL2.dll

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I have been trying to figure out why CMake is not adding the static libraries of SDL2. If I add the SDL2.dll file next to the executable, then it does work.

It al builds fine and the headers can be found nice and easily.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfKs8.png)

My CMakeList.txt looks like this. Trust me, I have tried everything but clearly I am doing something wrong.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
set (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

SET(SDL2_DIR ./lib)

project(SDL2Test)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(SDL2Test ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(SDL2Test Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SDL2Test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the sdl2-config.cmake:

```
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../include")

# Support both 32 and 64 bit builds
if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/x64/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/x64/SDL2main.lib")
else ()
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/x86/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/x86/SDL2main.lib")
endif ()

string(STRIP "${SDL2_LIBRARIES}" SDL2_LIBRARIES)
```

This is the Main.cpp

```
#include "SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "SDL2Test",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            640,
            480,
            0
    );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/x64/SDL2.lib` a **static** library or an **import** library (which doesn't work without `.dll`)?

Comment: What compiler do you use? `.lib` hints at MSVC, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys!
Yes indeed, I am using MSVC @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Tsyvarev It should be import library since the application doesn't run without it.
To make the program run I have to copy the .dll and put it next to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Your SDL2.lib is import library, that requires accompanying DLL in the runtime.

To use static library (one that is completely linked with your EXE and does not require DLL), you will need to build static version of SDL2.lib yourself.

Keep in mind that this is [discouraged by the author of SDL](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Static_linking)

Comment: Interesting. For MinGW, they provide a proper static library out of the box, as well as a dynamic one.

Comment: That is true with MinGW. I am trying to achieve Cross-Platform support, which is why I went for MSVC

Comment: I am trying to achieve your first solution. How can I make the CMake build a .dll to the executable? I thought target_link_libraries is enough @PiotrK